# EXE silent installation

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have following PowerShell script to install application without user intervention:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\UpgradeClientInstaller\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/S /v/qn"
```

by giving `/s` in argument list, it should install silently without user intervention but a popup is showing [image: powershell issue]

Even I try with `winrar.exe` and `zip.exe` files giving the same result. Is this right way to do?

Comment: Try providing the arguments as an actual list: `-ArgumentList '/s', '/v', '/qn'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers split the arguments not solving the problem, did you try with any exe file, is it work for you ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't look closely enough at the notification. The message comes from Windwos, not from the application. See if [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx) helps.

Comment: @RameshBolla hello man, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Kob_24 yes, i was able to solve the problem. moved to WiX Installer, have to provide answer file to install silently on remote machine.

Comment: @RameshBolla - Were you able to do it using powershell? It;s successful when executed using cmd

Comment: @sdevgd, Yes, I am able to install my exe on remote machine using power shell remote execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$pathvargs = {C:\Temp\UpgradeClientInstaller\setup.exe /S /v/qn }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $pathvargs
```

Comment: This works, but again I have to click on "Next", "Accept agreement" and then again click on "next", how to have all installed without any manual clicks?

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried the following command?

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks @Shreyas Ezhava

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath C:\setup.exe -Argument "/silent" -PassThru
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "\full\path\setup.exe" -ArgumentList '/S','/v','/qn' -passthru
```

The quotes of the execute file are not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

I know the post is super old, but I feel like I could share some insight on the matter

I had to do something similar a few years ago. When you click "install" on the prompt, all it's doing is adding the cert to the TrustedPublisher store. That prompt can be avoided if you manually add it to the cert manager prior to running the installer.
I found that if you install the program on a test machine, you can export the Cert from certmgr.msc. Then you can install the cert using:

```
certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" <PathTo.cerFile> >nul 2>nul
```

This will install the cert to the TrustedPublisher store therefore eliminating the need for that message to appear.

I hope this helps Ramesh as well as anyone else who finds this in the future

Answer (score 1):

Use this command it will not ask for any click on next and install the software.

Start-Process -Wait -ArgumentList "/silent" -PassThru  -FilePath 'C:\Users\filename.exe'

Answer (score 0):

```
$Arguments = @(
    "/S"
    "/V/qn"
    )

Start-Process -FilePath “application.exe” -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -2):

Your problem seems to be Windows UAC and not the script itself.

1. Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Security and Maintenance
2. Click Change User Account Control settings.
3. Set the slider to "Never Notify".

This may be risky - but it works.

Comment: Is there a way to install without UAC intervening?

Answer (score -2):

add the -NoNewWindow to stop the popup

Comment: I thought NoNewWindow only prevents starting a new command process, not surpressing any security related messages. The docs seem silent about that as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters . Are you sure that works for the specific  usecase as described in the question?